# Diagnosing a Sony Vaio laptop not booting after being dropped

Tags: laptop, hardware-failure, troubleshooting, sony-vaio

So basically, my Sony Vaio fall while I was watching a video, a moment later  a text showed up saying studf like it's shutting down to avoid/stop error on the system and when I turned it on, it showed Sony Vaio, but have a blank screen. I tried connecting it to monitor, check ram, but didn't work, now I'm inside the laptop, but don't know which parts to check, what can be the suspects of the fall?

Answer (score 0):

Three main things get damaged during a fall depending on how the device lands. Ideally, it hits relatively flat and only damages the outer plastic, sometimes you'll get lucky and only have cosmetic damage. If it lands on the display at all or the force of impact is enough in the right (wrong?) direction it can damage the LCD. In your case it sounds like the 3rd option, the spinning disks of the hard drive probably collided with the head and have damaged the data on your hard drive. Best bet would be to pull the hard drive out of that machine, connected to another machine where you can attempt to recover data from the drive. Ultimately, you may need to replace the drive entirely.

SSDs have no moving parts and aren't subject to this same issue. If you think there's any chance you may end up dropping it again you may want to look into an SSD instead. They're way more expensive but come with the perk of being way faster as well.

Comment: Would it be possible for me to check if the part is damaged? Maybe by a multimeter or some other ways?

Answer (score 0):

Like Mimp said, the impact of the fall probably caused the read/write head of the hard disk to gouge the platter, resulting in a corrupted sector. The only way to physically see a scratched platter is microscopically so that is not practical. You can buy a SATA to USB cable and plug your Vaio hard drive into another machine, run chkdsk on it to see if Windows can repair the sectors on its own.

If the damage is beyond repair, you may need to look into extracting whatever data you are able to salvage from the original drive and replacing it.

Answer (score 0):

Things to try:

- Bios setup , check drive status  ( DEL key or ESC or ?)
- Listen to HDD for click, click... ( of death)

  - i.e. damaged servo
- Windows Repair CD Chkdsk from command prompt, also MEMTEST
- Download free & burn > change boot order > Live Linux boot DVD
- Advanced Recovery Boot Function key F?
- replace HDD & get replacement OEM DVD for Windows.